# Converting C# DateTIme.TryParse() Function to Python

Tags: c#, python, datetime

I'm trying to write a python function that will mimic the c-sharp DateTime.TryParse() function. What string datetime formats does the library use is trying to convert a string to a DateTime object in c-sharp?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a similar method. You are going to have to catch the exception. If you would like to parse the string, follow the formats as specified in the python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Example: `strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: I completely understand that. I just wanted to know what specific formats c sharp uses, so I could write a python script that would be able to follow the same convention.

Comment: Then simply use the documentation I referred you to. It shows all the different formats.